# Adding a CASE into A Cake query join

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to add a Case statement to a query I'm developing. On one of the joins I need to add a conditional on which fields to join.
1. If field1 is not null use it
2. Else if use field2 if not null
3. else use fallbackField.

I have a working query using just sql.  But looking to convert it.
I also have a the multiple joins setup (just need the conditional in one)

The raw sql which works

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers c 
       INNER JOIN member_customers mc 
               ON c.id = mc.customer_id 
       INNER JOIN enums e 
               ON CASE 
                    WHEN e.source_id IS NOT NULL 
                         AND mc.id = e.source_id THEN 1 
                    WHEN e.org_id IS NOT NULL 
                         AND c.org_id = e.org_id THEN 1 
                    ELSE e.enum_name = 'Sold' 
                  END = 1 
       INNER JOIN enum_values ev 
               ON e.id = ev.enum_id 
                  AND mc.state = ev.enum_value 
WHERE  mc.user_id = 999
GROUP  BY c.NAME
```

The Cake conversion which I have so far

```
        $query = $this->Customers->MemberCustomers->find('all')
            ->contain(['Customers'])
            ->join([
                'c' => [
                    'table' => 'customers',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => 'c.id = MemberCustomers.customer_id'
                ],
                'e' => [
                    'table' => 'enums',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => '//where the conditions need to be'
                ],
                'ev' => [
                    'table' => 'enum_values',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => 'e.id = ev.enum_id AND MemberCustomers.state = ev.enum_value'
                ]
            ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.

```
$caseConditions = $query->newExpr()->addCase([
$query->newExpr()->add(['e.source_id IS  NULL AND MemberCustomers.id = e.source_id']),
$query->newExpr()->add(['e.source_id IS  NULL AND MemberCredentials.id = e.source_id'])
...
])
```

Than in the conditions portion

```
'conditions' => $caseConditions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'e' => [
    'table' => 'enums',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => 
        '(CASE WHEN e.source_id IS NOT NULL
        AND mc.id = e.source_id THEN 1
        WHEN e.org_id IS NOT NULL 
        AND c.org_id = e.org_id THEN 1 
        ELSE e.enum_name = 'Sold' 
        END) = 1'
]
```

Comment: Please write an explanation to the code you have provided. Something like, why the code in the question was not working or explain how your code works.